# Asynchronous code works independently, but not together. Not getting any exceptions, just timing out

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, async-await

I am writing a lambda function to add hosts to a SQS queue for a rolling restart. The code I have written works individually, but not together. Even when I hard code values in the constructor. This doesn't appear to be a memory/CPU. I tried running the function with 1GB of memory, even though it only uses about 80MB. The average execution time for the individual functions is about 0.5 seconds (shouldn't take more than about 1.5 seconds to execute in total). I did trying running this function with a 30 second timeout, but it still timed out.

I work behind a corporate proxy, and have to hand jam the code. I don't have an IDE or intellisense on my internet facing network. There may be typos here, but not in the actual code. I have omitted my module imports and variable declarations to save time. It isn't relevant to the issue at hand.

**EDIT**: I added the module imports and variable declarations to the first example to hopefully alleviate some confusion.

Here are just a few things I have tried. This does not work (timing out):

```
// Custom lambda layer
const { marklogic, aws } = require('nodejs-layer-lib'); 
const { HOSTS, DOMAIN, PORT, USERNAME, PASSWORD, RESTART_QUEUE_NAME } = process.env;

const params = [
  'format=json'
];

const options = {
  port: PORT,
  params: params,
  httpOptions: {
    headers: {
       'Authorization': `Basic ${Buffer.from(`${USERNAME}:${PASSWORD}`).toString('base64')}`
    },
    method: 'GET'
  }
};

const taskServers = (HOSTS.split(',') || []).map(host => {
  const _host = host.split(':');

  return {
    id: _host[0],
    name: `http://${_host[1].toLowerCase()}.${DOMAIN}`
  };
});

exports.handler = async () => {
  let hosts, queueUrl, addToQueueResults;

  try {
    hosts = (await marklogic.hosts.getHosts(taskServers, options) || []);
  } catch (e) { console.error('hosts', e); }

  try {
    queueUrl = await aws.sqs.getQueueUrlByName(RESTART_QUEUE_NAME);
  } catch (e) { console.error('queueUrl ', e); }

  try {
    addToQueueResults = await aws.sqs.addMessages(queueURL, hosts);
  } catch (e) { console.error('addToQueueResults ', e); }

  return {
    status: 200,
    body: addToQueueResults
  };
}
```

This does not work (timing out):

```
// Modules imports and variable declarations here...

exports.handler = async () => {
  const hosts = (await marklogic.hosts.getHosts(taskServers, options) || []);
  const queueUrl = await aws.sqs.getQueueUrlByName(RESTART_QUEUE_NAME);
  const addToQueueResults = await aws.sqs.addMessages(queueURL, hosts);

  return {
    status: 200,
    body: addToQueueResults
  };
}
```

This does not work (timing out):

```
// Modules imports and variable declarations here...

exports.handler = async () => {
  const hosts = (await marklogic.hosts.getHosts(taskServers, options) || []);
  const queueUrl = await aws.sqs.getQueueUrlByName('my-queue-name');
  const addToQueueResults = await aws.sqs.addMessages('http://queueurl.com', ['anything', 'in', 'here']); // Doesn't even need the queueUrl or hosts anymore

  return {
    status: 200,
    body: addToQueueResults
  };
}
```

This works. It will return the host objects I am expecting in the response:

```
// Modules imports and variable declarations here...

exports.handler = async () => {
  const hosts = (await marklogic.hosts.getHosts(taskServers, options) || []);

  return {
    status: 200,
    body: hosts 
  };
}
```

This works. It will get the queue url, then add messages to my SQS queue and return the SQS response:

```
// Modules imports and variable declarations here...

exports.handler = async () => {
  const queueUrl = await aws.sqs.getQueueUrlByName(RESTART_QUEUE_NAME);
  const addToQueueResults = await aws.sqs.addMessages(queueUrl , ['anything', 'in', 'here']);

  return {
    status: 200,
    body: addToQueueResults
  };
}
```

I tried implementing the Async handler in [AWS Lambda function handler in Node.js](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-handler.html) and reviewed many AWS Lambda execution troubleshooting documents. The marklogic management API runs on port 8002 by default and I think the aws-sdk module uses http/https (80/443), so I don't think the ports are getting tied up.

What am I missing here?

**EDIT 2**: This has something to do with how promises are handled with AWS Lambda. I cannot find much information about this. Even following the instructions in [AWS Lambda function handler in Node.js](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-handler.html) for "Async Handlers" I cannot get this to work. It works perfectly fine locally with or without my custom lambda layer.

Node.js runtime: 12.x (I didn't mention this before)

This also doesn't work (timing out):

```
// Modules imports and variable declarations here...

exports.handler = async function (event) {
  const promise = function () {
      return new Promise(async function (resolve, reject) {
        try {
          const hosts = await marklogic.hosts.getHosts(taskServers, options) || [];
          const queueUrl = await aws.sqs.getQueueUrlByName(RESTART_QUEUE_NAME);
          const addToQueueResults = await aws.sqs.addMessages(queueUrl, hosts); 
          resolve({
            status: 200,
            body: addToQueueResults
          });
        } catch (error) {
           reject({
             status: 500,
             error: error
           });
        }
      });
  };

  return promise(); // Throws error without constructor despite the AWS doc example
}
```

Unless someone AWS Lambda genius has ran into a similar issue before with Node.js, I am just going to convert it into 2 lambda functions and use Step Functions to process them.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Are there any exceptions? Does it log something?

Comment: Have you tried additional logging after each try/catch of hosts, queueurl and addToQueueResults, to check which are succeeding and where the timeout is occurring?

Comment: @kichik Sorry, I should have added more context. The function is timing out. Each operation only takes about 0.5 seconds to run, but it still times out with a 30 second maximum time out.

Comment: @LeighMathieson It is timing out at the first try/catch. I just don't understand why. It works fine without the sqs code. The sqs code works fine without the marklogic code.

Comment: How do you initialize marklogic and sqs? It should be important.

Comment: @kgiannakakis They are coming from a lambda layer. The specific code is: `const { marklogic, aws } = require('nodejs-layer-lib');`. What about the initialization could cause an issue? Let me know if you want to know anything else.

Comment: I suspect some issue with the layer, perhaps add some additional logging in the layer and see exactly where the issue is..? In general I find unexpected timeouts are usually SG (Security Group) related and lambda can’t access resources it needs & hangs indefinitely. (Unsure why it would work without the sqs call though..) unless.. the layer sets AWS to say region eu-west-1 and you overwrite some aws config (which was working in the layer) with the sqs init.. eg to eu-west-2 (so they work individually.. but not cross-region.. or similar..)

Comment: To clarify, does any code in the marklogic layer also require AWS..? As it may be overwritten by the additional init of AWS

Comment: @LeighMathieson This isn't a SG thing, since they work independently. The function is actually attached to the same VPC as the servers it is communicating with. I actually do override the AWS region in the layer, but I doubt it is this. We have an AWS Outpost on our intranet, we don't use the same regions as the commercial AWS. We basically use the same region for everything. The marklogic module doesn't use anything from the aws module. It uses the http node module to make a call to a REST API on port 8002. I do appreciate the help! Let me know if you have any other suggestions.

Comment: Must be something in the layer we can’t see from this info.  Causing it to not connect correctly.. out of ideas I’m afraid other than further logging of everything including in the layer..!  (I didn’t think lambda had access externally without SG applying including port.. eg with RDS you need to set VPC config, and also essential to add an SG.  But if you say it works without that then can’t be SG!)

Comment: @LeighMathieson No worries. I am going to add additional logging and see if I can get some new information. At the moment I am just going to get the permissions/roles to create a step function and use two lambda functions. Seems a little unnecessary, but this is just such a weird issue. If I figure it out I will post an answer here.

Comment: Yeah if you figure it out pls do let me know! You could just trigger a 2nd lambda by the 1st lambda (to avoid the step function) in the short term

Comment: No answer to contribute yet, but there is a bug on this line: `hosts = (await marklogic.hosts.getHosts(taskServers, options) || []);` - the parentheses need to be on the other side of the `||`. Should be `hosts = (await marklogic.hosts.getHosts(taskServers, options)) || [];`

Comment: @Codebling There are typos, but it's just because I had to manually type the code. The code itself is on another network and I don't have an IDE on my internet facing network. The issue is likely with the Lambda layer I am importing, or a clash with the marklogic requests and the sqs requests. Individually the code works, but together it does not.

Comment: I understand. I know that line is likely not responsible for the problem, but if the parentheses are placed like that, `[]` will never be used and `hosts` could still be null. If it's a typo, that's fine. Figured I'd mention it because it's a pretty subtle mistake

Answer (score 0):

There was a typo in queueUrl (I imagine not that, but worth a try!)

Please run:

```
// Custom lambda layer
const { marklogic, aws } = require('nodejs-layer-lib');

const { HOSTS, DOMAIN, PORT, USERNAME, PASSWORD, RESTART_QUEUE_NAME } = process.env;

const params = [
    'format=json'
];

const options = {
    port: PORT,
    params,
    httpOptions: {
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Basic ${Buffer.from(`${USERNAME}:${PASSWORD}`).toString('base64')}`
        },
        method: 'GET'
    }
};

const taskServers = (HOSTS.split(',') || []).map(host => {
    const _host = host.split(':');

    return {
        id: _host[0],
        name: `http://${_host[1].toLowerCase()}.${DOMAIN}`
    };
});

exports.handler = async () => {
    let hosts, queueUrl, addToQueueResults;

    try {
        hosts = (await marklogic.hosts.getHosts(taskServers, options) || []);
    } catch (e) { console.error('hosts', e); }

    try {
        queueUrl = await aws.sqs.getQueueUrlByName(RESTART_QUEUE_NAME);
    } catch (e) { console.error('queueUrl ', e); }

    try {
        addToQueueResults = await aws.sqs.addMessages(queueUrl, hosts);
    } catch (e) { console.error('addToQueueResults ', e); }

    return {
        status: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify(addToQueueResults)
    };
};
```

// keeping the same format.. ^^

If no luck - what is on my mind, is as aws-sdk is included out of the box in lambda.. it's not customary to require it extraneously via a layer and although it may not look to be imported at top level by marklogic, it may be bundled deep within marklogic, then when you import AWS and change config (in the layer) it overwrites it

Let's find out..:

Step 1:

So, this you say should work.. if we ignore the AWS import, and just import marklogic?

```
// Custom lambda layer
// const { marklogic, aws } = require('nodejs-layer-lib'); // ignoring AWS for now
const { marklogic } = require('nodejs-layer-lib');

const { HOSTS, DOMAIN, PORT, USERNAME, PASSWORD, RESTART_QUEUE_NAME } = process.env;

const params = [
    'format=json'
];

const options = {
    port: PORT,
    params,
    httpOptions: {
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Basic ${Buffer.from(`${USERNAME}:${PASSWORD}`).toString('base64')}`
        },
        method: 'GET'
    }
};

const taskServers = (HOSTS.split(',') || []).map(host => {
    const _host = host.split(':');

    return {
        id: _host[0],
        name: `http://${_host[1].toLowerCase()}.${DOMAIN}`
    };
});

exports.handler = async () => {
    // let hosts, queueUrl, addToQueueResults;
    let hosts;

    try {
        hosts = (await marklogic.hosts.getHosts(taskServers, options) || []);
        console.log('hosts => ', hosts);

        // queueUrl = await aws.sqs.getQueueUrlByName(RESTART_QUEUE_NAME);

        // addToQueueResults = await aws.sqs.addMessages(queueUrl, hosts);

        return {
            status: 200,
            body: JSON.stringify(hosts)
        };
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('error => ', error);

        throw error;
    }
};
```

Ok, so if that works..:

Step 2 (Please set the region for SQS and also hard code in the queueUrl):

```
// Custom lambda layer
// const { marklogic, aws } = require('nodejs-layer-lib');
const { marklogic } = require('nodejs-layer-lib');

const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

AWS.config.update({ region: 'eu-west-1' }); // Please set region accordingly
const sqs = new AWS.SQS({ apiVersion: '2012-11-05' });

const { HOSTS, DOMAIN, PORT, USERNAME, PASSWORD, RESTART_QUEUE_NAME } = process.env;

const params = [
    'format=json'
];

const options = {
    port: PORT,
    params,
    httpOptions: {
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Basic ${Buffer.from(`${USERNAME}:${PASSWORD}`).toString('base64')}`
        },
        method: 'GET'
    }
};

const taskServers = (HOSTS.split(',') || []).map(host => {
    const _host = host.split(':');

    return {
        id: _host[0],
        name: `http://${_host[1].toLowerCase()}.${DOMAIN}`
    };
});

exports.handler = async () => {
    let hosts, addToQueueResults;

    try {
        hosts = (await marklogic.hosts.getHosts(taskServers, options) || []);
        console.log('hosts => ', hosts);

        const queueUrl = 'Please hard code the queueUrl for now';

        const sqsParams = {
            MessageBody: hosts,
            QueueUrl: queueUrl
        };

        addToQueueResults = await sqs.sendMessage(sqsParams).promise();

        console.log('addToQueueResults => ', addToQueueResults);

        return {
            status: 200,
            body: JSON.stringify(addToQueueResults)
        };
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('error => ', error);

        throw error;
    }
};
```

IF.. that doesn't work.. then Step 3..  move the require of marklogic to below the require of AWS and setting the region in this last example.. (so any deeply nested marklogic AWS logic we're unaware of now overwrites your AWS require..) re-run it.. fingers crossed :-)

Comment: This is a good idea. I might actually take it a step further and remove the lambda layer completely. Then, I can confirm whether the bug is related to the layer itself. I'll let you know what happens.

Comment: Any update @dj11223344 ..?

Comment: Yes. Sorry. I should have shot you a comment. The answer you provided did not work unfortunately. I tried a few more things. I have pretty much given up at this point. I am just going to use a step function to chain a couple of lambda functions. The code works perfectly fine locally. So it has an Lambda specific issue.